# Android calculate scrollTo position in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android

I have HorizontalScrollView with few TextViews. Each TextView might contain text of different length.

How should I calculate correct offset to scroll to using "scrollTo(x, y)"?

Scrolling works, but different than expected.
I've tried various things (getLocationOnScreen(), getMeasuredWidth(), getWidth() on each child element and them adding them togetehr) but I still can't get result I like. View is scrolled a bit too far or not enough.

**Solution**

When HSV has multiple elements with different width you can center on each of them like this:

```
for (TextView el : requiresFocus) {
    if (el.getText().equals(requiresFocus)) {
        offsetX = ((el.getLeft() + el.getRight()) / 2) - (myHSV.this.getWidth() / 2);
        scrollTo(offsetX, 0);
        break;
    }
}
```

with `((el.getLeft() + el.getRight()) / 2)` you will get center of the element and with `(myHSV.this.getWidth() / 2)` you will get center of the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
int x, y;
x = myTextView.getLeft();
y = myTextView.getTop();

myHsv.scrollTo(x, y);
```

`getLeft()` and `getTop()` should return the coordinates relative to the parent view (that is, the `HorizontalScrollView` in this instance.

Comment: Not quite, but you led me on the right path :) Thank you!
Updated my question on with code how I solved it.

Comment: Ah I see, didn't realize you wanted to scroll to the center. :) Glad you got it working.