# Center HorizontalScrollView and LinearLayout when the layout is larger than the screen

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I'm working on a Family Tree app. Now, the tree view can be large, and I allow the users to navigate left and right (for example if you have 7 siblings). But when I open the tree view, it always start from the left corner and you can scroll to the right to see more. I want to tree view to open always in the middle of the layout.

Here is the code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/HorizontalScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_green" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Top_Level_View_Family_Tree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"  >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView_view_family_members_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="Family Tree"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_large" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Family_Tree_parentLL"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"  >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Family_Tree_yourLL"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Family_Tree_siblingLL"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Family_Tree_childLL"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Here is the app: 
http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/310/appa.png

Great Help:
[Android calculate scrollTo position in HorizontalScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002282/android-calculate-scrollto-position-in-horizontalscrollview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to position it in code, can't do it in XML.  Use the [`scrollTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) method of `HorizontalScrollView` to accomplish this.  You'll have to calculate the position that you need to scroll to yourself based on the width of the top level LinearLayout.

Something like the following:

```
HorizontalScrollView hView = findViewById( R.id.HorizontalScrollView01 );
LinearLayout lin = findViewById( R.id.Top_Level_View_Family_Tree );

int width = lin.getWidth();
hView.scrollTo( width / 2, 0 );
```

Now, you're going to need to edit that `scrollTo` part because I'm sure it's not the right position to scroll to, it probably scrolls to a position on the left side of the view, and what I did assumes that it goes to the center.  You'll have to play around with the calculation to make it do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Ralgha, but how do I do it? I don't have an instance of HorizontalScrollView object in the code.

Comment: Thanks, i combined your answer with this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002282/android-calculate-scrollto-position-in-horizontalscrollview